# What should I do with my diamonds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am relatively new to Minecraft, and am playing my second survival game (The first one I left because some mods I installed cleared the map, almost like re-creating the world). Anyways, I mined some diamonds today (my first time). I have 10 of them. What are the most useful tools I can craft with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no "right" way to use your diamonds. This answer will cover what I'd recommend doing with them, although it really depends on your playstyle.

First of all, diamonds can be used to create the following items:

- Diamond Pickaxe (3 diamonds)
- Diamond Sword (2 d)
- Diamond Axe (3 d)
- Diamond Shovel (1 d)
- Diamond Hoe (2 d)
- Enchantment Table (2 d)
- Diamond Boots (4 d)
- Diamond Leggings (7 d)
- Diamond Chestplate (8 d)
- Diamond Helmet (5 d)
- Block of Diamond (9 d)
- Firework Star (1 d)
- Jukebox (1 d)

With your 10 diamonds I would firstly make a Diamond Pickaxe and a sword.

Using the pickaxe you can mine obsidian and create an Enchanting Table and, with bookcases set up, this will allow you to enchant any of your tools provided you have to EXP and lapis to do so.

Aim for some good enchantments on your sword and pickaxe. With your last 3 diamonds you can create another pickaxe. Ideally I would say that you want a Fortune III pickaxe (get more diamonds/coal/lapis/redstone per ore), and an Efficiency IV pickaxe (really fast); Unbreaking III on either of these is also great.

The only items I would really avoid with your first diamonds are the Jukebox, Firework Star, and Diamond Hoe. Anything else is useful. For example if you find yourself dying a lot, making a chestplate and a sword might be wise.

Comment: Thank you :) Is the diamond pickaxe needed for mining anything else except obsidian?

Comment: @BlackHawk Nope, but it's faster at mining in general and lasts a lot longer than an iron pickaxe.